# Trying to send emails produces ActivityNotFoundException or PermissionDenial

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-activity, android-securityexception

I'm trying to send email using ComposeActivityGmail. I've tried 3 approaches. First one is the simplest Intent.setClassName:

```
sendIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName( "com.google.android.gm", "ComposeActivityGmail" ) );
```

With this I have the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=myemail@gmail.com cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmail (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{30a898b6 10871:org.madebyalex.myperiod/u0a255} (pid=10871, uid=10255) not exported from uid 10067
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2468)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1563)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3755)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:77)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3716)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4036)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3998)
   at org.madebyalex.myperiod.EmailMessage.sendMessage(EmailMessage.java:93)
   at org.madebyalex.myperiod.SecurityFragment$2.onClick(SecurityFragment.java:159)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

The second approach is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627368/send-email-through-intent-securityexception) using PackageManager:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    sendIntent.setType( "plain/text" );
    sendIntent.setData( Uri.parse( receivers.get( 0 ) ) );

    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = packageManager.queryIntentActivities( sendIntent, 0 );
    String className = "";

    for( ResolveInfo info : matches ){
        if( info.activityInfo.packageName.equals( "com.google.android.gm" ) ){
            className = info.activityInfo.name;
            if( className != null && !className.isEmpty() ){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    sendIntent.setClassName( "com.google.android.gm", className );
    Log.e("ERROR", "CLASS NAME: "+className);

    sendIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getSubject() );
    sendIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message+"\n" );
    context.startActivity( sendIntent );
```

With this approach the following exception is raised:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.gm/ComposeActivityGmail}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1868)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1568)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3755)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:77)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3716)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4036)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3998)
   at org.madebyalex.myperiod.EmailMessage.sendMessage(EmailMessage.java:93)
   at org.madebyalex.myperiod.SecurityFragment$2.onClick(SecurityFragment.java:159)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

And using this code the very same above exception is raised:

```
sendIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName( "com.google.android.gm", "ComposeActivityGmail" ) );
```

Some answers on SO says to declare this Activity on Android manifest. Doing this AndroidStudio complains the "android.gm/ComposeActivityGmail" part:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gm/ComposeActivityGmail"
    android:screenOrientation="locked"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Inserting this simple code in AndroidManifest.xml AndroidStudio complains: Unresolved class.

```
<activity android:name=".ComposeActivityGmail"/>
```

How to solve this if all of these solutions fail?

Comment: Did you resolve this Issue?

Comment: @Nivedh Yes, but not using any of proposed solutions. I have used Intent.createChooser

Comment: So a chooser will come right? It wont direct directly to Gmail right.

Answer (score 0):

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.gm/ComposeActivityGmail}; **have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

declare your activity in manifest and add internet permission, like this

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...

<activity android:name=".ComposeActivityGmail"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { Constants.CONTACT_EMAIL_ADDRESS });
        final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        String className = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.google.android.gm")) {
                className = info.activityInfo.name;

                if(className != null && !className.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", className);

        try {
            startActivity(emailIntent);
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // handle error
        }
```

Comment: This code is a little modification of the code I shown.

Comment: I was getting the same exception as yours and on using my snippet, it worked. If you tried the snippet shown above, and if it doesnt work, then kindly mention.

Answer (score 0):

After new update of gmail, google has changed the compose activity name. So instead of giving static value, please use below code to resolve your issue.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        String className = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.google.android.gm")) {
                className = info.activityInfo.name;

                if(className != null && !className.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", className);
```